# Javascript function to turn URLs and email addresses into clickable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there a Javascript library that exposes a function to automatically turn URLs and email addresses into clickable links? Basically I'm looking for something that duplicates the Rails helper [auto_link()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001752).

Answer (score 8):

[Autolink](http://kawika.org/jquery/autolink/) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My bad, I totally misread/misunderstood the question. Left original answer for informative purposes.**

Not off the top of my head. However it doesn't sound too hard to write one yourself:

```
function UrlToLink(url) {
    // 1. check if url IS a url or email using a regex
    // 2. if it isnt return null/false
    // 3. create a DOM `<a></a>` element and populate the href attribute with url (mailto:url if email) and the inner text
    // 4. return element
}
```

Usage:

```
document.appendChild(UrlToLink("http://a.url.com/"));
```

Finding regex's to match url's and email addresses isnt very hard ex: [url](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url), [email](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email)